# How to reuse Testcontainers between multiple SpringBootTests?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, testcontainers

I'm using TestContainers with Spring Boot to run unit tests for repositories like this:

```
@Testcontainers
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("itest")
@SpringBootTest(classes = RouteTestingCheapRouteDetector.class)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = AlwaysFailingRouteRepositoryShould.Initializer.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@Tag("docker")
@Tag("database")
class AlwaysFailingRouteRepositoryShould {

  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  @Container
  private static final PostgreSQLContainer database =
      new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:9.6")
          .withDatabaseName("database")
          .withUsername("postgres")
          .withPassword("postgres");
```

But now I have 14 of these tests and every time a test is run a new instance of Postgres is spun up. Is it possible to reuse the same instance across all tests? The [Singleton pattern](https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/manual_lifecycle_control/) doesn't help since every test starts a new application.

I've also tried `testcontainers.reuse.enable=true` in `.testcontainers.properties` and `.withReuse(true)`, but that didn't help.

Comment: Did you try the withReuse(true) option?

Comment: @P3trur0: Yes. And `testcontainers.reuse.enable=true` - doesn't help.

Comment: Try to place container instance into separate `@TestConfiguration` as a `@Bean` and then import this configuration in all your relevant tests.

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko: Tried that, but it's needed in the `@ContextConfiguration(initializers` and I can't get it to work there.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can't use the JUnit Jupiter annotation `@Container` if you want to have reusable containers. This annotation ensures to stop the container [after each test](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/2352).

What you need is the singleton container approach, and use e.g. `@BeforeAll` to start your containers. Even though you then have `.start()` in multiple tests, Testcontainers won't start a new container if you opted-in for reusability using both `.withReuse(true)` on your container definition AND the following `.testcontainers.properties` file in your home directory:

```
testcontainers.reuse.enable=true
```

A simple example might look like the following:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class SomeIT {

  public static GenericContainer postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer().
    withReuse(true);

  @BeforeAll
  public static void beforeAll() {
    postgreSQLContainer.start();
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {

  }

}
```

and another integration test:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class SecondIT {

  public static GenericContainer postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer().
    withReuse(true);

  @BeforeAll
  public static void beforeAll() {
    postgreSQLContainer.start();
  }

  @Test
  public void secondTest() {

  }

}
```

There is currently a [PR that adds documentation](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/pull/2555) about this

I've put together a blog post explaining [how to reuse containers with Testcontainers](https://rieckpil.de/reuse-containers-with-testcontainers-for-fast-integration-tests/) in detail.

Comment: Many thanks. Then I also need to increase my `max_connections` with `.withCommand("postgres -c max_connections=200")`. How can I control the lifetime of reusable containers?

Comment: I can't answer this question. Maybe it's worth having a look at the PR which introduced the feature: https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/pull/1781

Comment: Where is testcontainers.reuse.enable=true documented?

Comment: Is there a way to configure `testcontainers.reuse.enable=true` elsewhere? I don't want reusable containers to be dependant on the developer's laptop configuration

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ways to configure this property. Take a look at the [Configuration locations section](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/configuration/) of the Testcontainers documentation.

Comment: You can't set `testcontainers.reuse.enable` via classpath. [See this comment](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/3780#issuecomment-776562459).

Comment: @rieckpil how can we ensure that it is reusing the same container as I applied these settings and I do not see any time difference in my integration test run time. it seems to same with these conditions enabled and disabled. thanks

Comment: Take a look at docker ps while your tests are running. You should only see a single container being used. If you are on Linux/macOS `watch -n 1 docker ps` may be handy

Comment: @vault You can do this via `TestcontainersConfiguration.getInstance().updateUserConfig("testcontainers.reuse.enable", "true");` before starting the container

Comment: There are 2 calls of new PostgreSQLContainer()
But only one container will be used. Is it correct ?

Comment: Yes, only one container will be created for the tests

Comment: After the last test, Ryuk will still take care of shutting down the container, won't it ?

Comment: For some reasons my containers are not reused: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77144407/why-testcontainer-is-not-reused-in-spring-boot-test

Answer (score 12):

Accepted answer is great but the problem is you still have to repeat the configurations(creating, starting and etc.) for each integration tests. It would be better to have simpler configuration with fewer lines of code. I think cleaner version would be using JUnit 5 extensions.

This is how I solved the problem. Below sample uses MariaDB container but the concept is applicable to all.

1. Create the container config holding class:

```java
public class AppMariaDBContainer extends MariaDBContainer<AppMariaDBContainer> {

    private static final String IMAGE_VERSION = "mariadb:10.5";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "my-db";
    private static final String USERNAME = "user";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "strong-password";

    public static AppMariaDBContainer container = new AppMariaDBContainer()
            .withDatabaseName(DATABASE_NAME)
            .withUsername(USERNAME)
            .withPassword(PASSWORD);

    public AppMariaDBContainer() {
        super(IMAGE_VERSION);
    }

}
```

2. Create an extension class that starts the container and sets the `DataSource` properties. And run migrations if needed:

```java
public class DatabaseSetupExtension implements BeforeAllCallback {

    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) {
        AppMariaDBContainer.container.start();
        updateDataSourceProps(AppMariaDBContainer.container);
        //migration logic here (if needed)
    }

    private void updateDataSourceProps(AppMariaDBContainer container) {
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.url", container.getJdbcUrl());
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.username", container.getUsername());
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.password", container.getPassword());
    }

}
```

3. Add `@ExtendWith` to your test class

```java
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(DatabaseSetupExtension.class)
class ApplicationIntegrationTests {

    @Test
    void someTest() {
    }

}
```

Another test

```java
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(DatabaseSetupExtension.class)
class AnotherIntegrationTests {

    @Test
    void anotherTest() {
    }

}
```

Comment: Should be `@ExtendWith(DatabaseSetupExtension.class)`

Comment: For some reasons my containers are not reused: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77144407/why-testcontainer-is-not-reused-in-spring-boot-test

Answer (score 10):

If you decide go forward with the [singleton pattern](https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/manual_lifecycle_control/#singleton-containers), mind the warning in "[Database containers launched via JDBC URL scheme](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/#database-containers-launched-via-jdbc-url-scheme)". I took hours till I note that, even though I was using the [singleton pattern](https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/manual_lifecycle_control/#singleton-containers), an additional container was always being created mapped on a different port.

In summary, do not use the test containers JDBC (host-less) URIs, such as `jdbc:tc:postgresql:<image-tag>:///<databasename>`, if you need use the [singleton pattern](https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/manual_lifecycle_control/#singleton-containers).

Answer (score 5):

Using either singleton containers or reusable containers are possible solutions but because they don't scope the life-cycle of the container to that of the application context both are less then ideal.

It is however possible to scope the container to the application contexts lifecycle by using a `ContextCustomizerFactory` and [I've written about this in more detail in a blog post](https://logarithmicwhale.com/posts/faster-tests-by-resuing-testcontainers-in-spring-boot/).

In a test use:

```java
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest
@EnabledPostgresTestContainer
class DemoApplicationTest {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        log.info("Hello world");
    }

}
```

Then enable the annotation in `META-INF/spring.factories`:

```
org.springframework.test.context.ContextCustomizerFactory=\
  com.logarithmicwhale.demo.EnablePostgresTestContainerContextCustomizerFactory
```

Which can be implemented as:

```java
public class EnablePostgresTestContainerContextCustomizerFactory implements ContextCustomizerFactory {

    @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @Inherited
    public @interface EnabledPostgresTestContainer {
    }

    @Override
    public ContextCustomizer createContextCustomizer(Class<?> testClass,
            List<ContextConfigurationAttributes> configAttributes) {
        if (!(AnnotatedElementUtils.hasAnnotation(testClass, EnabledPostgresTestContainer.class))) {
            return null;
        }
        return new PostgresTestContainerContextCustomizer();
    }

    @EqualsAndHashCode // See ContextCustomizer java doc
    private static class PostgresTestContainerContextCustomizer implements ContextCustomizer {

        private static final DockerImageName image = DockerImageName
                .parse("postgres")
                .withTag("14.1");

        @Override
        public void customizeContext(ConfigurableApplicationContext context, MergedContextConfiguration mergedConfig) {
            var postgresContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>(image);
            postgresContainer.start();
            var properties = Map.<String, Object>of(
                    "spring.datasource.url", postgresContainer.getJdbcUrl(),
                    "spring.datasource.username", postgresContainer.getUsername(),
                    "spring.datasource.password", postgresContainer.getPassword(),
                    // Prevent any in memory db from replacing the data source
                    // See @AutoConfigureTestDatabase
                    "spring.test.database.replace", "NONE"
            );
            var propertySource = new MapPropertySource("PostgresContainer Test Properties", properties);
            context.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(propertySource);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm working on a reusable testcontainers solution myself and really liked your approach a lot, but I'm testing it and it seems that `return new PostgresTestContainerContextCustomizer();` will create a new instance every time it'll get hit, and that will dirty-up the context, forcing spring boot to reload it.
Do I understand it wrong? Maybe it'll be best to cache the `ContextCustomizer` as a static field/singleton so it won't be created for every test class?

Comment: I'm guessing you missed this in the example `@EqualsAndHashCode // See ContextCustomizer java doc` . The Javadoc explains why you need equals and hashcode and how that relates to the behaviour you see right now.

Comment: See it in action here! https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/main/generators/server/templates/src/test/java/package/config/TestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory.java.ejs

Comment: @Tcharl very cool!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77144407/why-testcontainer-is-not-reused-in-spring-boot-test

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer has the caveat that the container will survive the execution of the tests, which may be not desirable as it can make your tests run not reproducible.

If the goal is to have only one PostgreSQL container instance across multiple test classes and have it discarded at the end of the test phase, it can be easily achieved without relying on reusable testcontainers.

First create an abstract class that will be in charge of the setup of the needed testcontainers

```
public abstract class BaseIntegrationTest {

    @ServiceConnection
    protected static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> dbContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>(
            DockerImageName.parse("postgres")
                    .withTag("15.4"))
            .withDatabaseName("testcontainer")
            .withUsername("user")
            .withPassword("pass");
 
    static {
        dbContainer.start();
    }
}
```

Implement each test class as an extension of this abstract class

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class BootstrapApplicationTest extends BaseIntegrationTest {

    @Test
    @DisplayName("My test case")
    void myTest() throws Exception {

        ...
    }

}
```

Notice that the @TestContainers annotation is not used here as it tells Spring to create a container per test class.

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow the guide from the testcontainers documentation. about the [Singleton pattern](https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/manual_lifecycle_control/#singleton-containers). As they say - it is an option for JUnit5.
Do not use the @Testcontainers annotation and @Container annotation. Those are related to the JUnit4.
Also add to your class path testcontainers.properties file with:

```
testcontainers.reuse.enable=true
```

That did the trick for me.

Comment: its do not work. its do not see file in classpath and do not override default file

Comment: Try also to remove the Testcontainers annotation. For jUnit5 that do the trick for me. Also use base test class with static block in which to start the containers.

Comment: @Mikhail It does not see file in classpath because of conflict with Ryuk container. To fix it, go to IntelliJ Run Configuration and set environment variable TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED to equal true.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure how `@Testcontainers` works, but I suspect it might work per class.

Just make your singleton static as described in [Singleton pattern](https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/manual_lifecycle_control/)
and get it in every test from your signleton holder, don't define it in every test class.

Comment: "The Singleton pattern doesn't help since every test starts a new application."