# Micronaut to reuse testcontainer

Tags: micronaut, testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

I am using Micronaut 2.4.0 and using testContainers for SQL Server Integration testing.

Here is my gradle.build

```
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:testcontainers")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:mssqlserver")
```

Here is application.yml for test

```
    url: jdbc:tc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=test-db
    username: sa
    password: sa
    driverClassName: org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
```

These are the only changes and micronaut handles creating and starting of testcontainers.

**Problem**

For each test classes, it creates new container.
Most of the time test takes is in container creation.

Is there a way we can re-use the container ? (clearing the DB might still be okay)

Comment: I'm not sure if the Testcontainers re-use feature works with the JDBC support. With a manual container definition, it will definitely work (as seen in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62425598/how-to-reuse-testcontainers-between-multiple-springboottests/62443261#62443261)). You can find a detailed example also [here](https://rieckpil.de/reuse-containers-with-testcontainers-for-fast-integration-tests/) (using Spring Boot, but the setup is similar).

Comment: It is easy in spring botth, same does not work in micronaut. application.yml has the connection string. Need some way to initialize testcontainers before app starts

Comment: Do you use annotation `@Container` ? If yes you shouldn't. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62443261/696714

Answer (score 4):

Late reply but, in case someone stumbles on this.

Try adding TC_REUSABLE=true into the jdbc URL

i.e: jdbc:tc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=test-db/TC_INITSCRIPT=db/customer_database_schema.sql&TC_REUSABLE=true

Comment: This works. My previous config "testcontainers.reuse.enable: true" didn't work, it's probably a setting for Spring Boot not Micronaut

Answer (score 0):

The other answer could be right.

I got it working with `TC_DAEMON=true` parameter in jdbc URL

So, it becomes

`url: jdbc:tc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=mydb?TC_DAEMON=true`

**Edit**

Eventually I moved away from test containers and now starting with docker manually

Answer (score 0):

Actually better approach will be creating singleton class with reusable container and applying it to every test which uses database

```
@Testcontainers
public class PostgresContainer implements TestPropertyProvider {

    private static final PostgreSQLContainer POSTGRE_SQL_CONTAINER;

    static {
        POSTGRE_SQL_CONTAINER = new PostgreSQLContainer(DockerImageName.parse("postgres:latest"))
                .withDatabaseName("test")
                .withPassword("test")
                .withUsername("test");
        POSTGRE_SQL_CONTAINER.start();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getProperties() {
        return Map.of(
                "datasource.default.jdbc-url", POSTGRE_SQL_CONTAINER.getJdbcUrl(),
                "datasource.default.username", POSTGRE_SQL_CONTAINER.getUsername(),
                "datasource.default.password", POSTGRE_SQL_CONTAINER.getPassword()
        );
    }
}

@MicronautTest
class BaseDatabaseTest extends PostgresContainer {...}
```

Note that with Singleton pattern, container will be created only once and be reused in every single test class