# When should we create tables/views/stored procedures etc when using TestContainers

Tags: spring-boot, testcontainers

Since our tests requires many DB tables/views/storedprocs, would it be slow to create them for each test class initialization ? So where's the appropriate place to do it ?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards,

SetNug

Comment: See Singleton Containers https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/manual_lifecycle_control/#singleton-containers

Comment: And yes, creating it for each test class will generally slow down the test suite and should be avoided.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62425598/how-to-reuse-testcontainers-between-multiple-springboottests/74779653#74779653