# How to update spring boot properties in a cucumber, TestNg, springboot Project

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber, testng, spring-boot-test, testcontainers

I am using Test-Ng, Cucumber, Spring-boot and test-containers for my automation project.

I am trying to update the property using **@DynamicPropertySource** annotation, but it is not working as expected.

**Sample Test Class**

```
import com.sample.PromotionsService;
import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertySource;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer;
import org.testcontainers.containers.Network;
import org.testcontainers.images.PullPolicy;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.wiremock.integrations.testcontainers.WireMockContainer;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

@Slf4j
@DirtiesContext
public class PromotionTests{


    private static final Network network = Network.newNetwork();

    private static final WireMockContainer wiremockServer = new WireMockContainer("wiremock/wiremock:2.35.0")
            .withNetwork(network)
            .withNetworkAliases("mockServer")
            .withMappingFromResource("weatherMock", "MockData/weatherMock.json")
            .withMappingFromResource("locationMock", "MockData/locationMock.json");

    private static final GenericContainer springBootContainer = new GenericContainer(DockerImageName.parse("promotion-service-image"))
            .withNetwork(network);


   @Autowired
   PromotionsService promotions;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("defaultRestTemplate")
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Before("@testContainer")
    public void setUpMockServers() {
        wiremockServer.start();

        springBootContainer.dependsOn(wiremockServer)
                .withImagePullPolicy(PullPolicy.defaultPolicy())
                .withExposedPorts(20100)
                .withEnv("weather_data_host", getMockHost())
                .withEnv("location_data_host", getMockHost())
                .withStartupTimeout(Duration.of(5, ChronoUnit.MINUTES));
        springBootContainer.start();

    }
    private static String getMockHost() {
        return String.format("http://%s:%s", "mockServer", "8080");
    }

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void setApplicationUnderTestHost(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("promotionService.host", () -> String.format("https://%s:%s", springBootContainer.getHost(), springBootContainer.getFirstMappedPort()));
    }

    @After("@testContainer")
    public void stopContainer() {
        wiremockServer.stop();
        springBootContainer.stop();
    }

    @Given("I am mock dependency using wiremock testcontainers")
    public void iAmMockDependencyUsingWiremockTestcontainers() {

        log.info("dataIngestion server host: {}", springBootContainer.getHost());
        log.info("dataIngestion server port: {}", springBootContainer.getFirstMappedPort());

        //should call the spring bootContainer host
        dataIngestionService.ingestData(new data());

        String url = String.format("https://%s:%s/retrieveData", springBootContainer.getHost(), springBootContainer.getFirstMappedPort());
        var response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Object.class);
        Assert.assertTrue(response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful());

    }
}
```

Here is my cucumber runner class for TestNG

```
import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberContextConfiguration;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.testng.FeatureWrapper;
import io.cucumber.testng.PickleWrapper;
import io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/features/",
        glue = {"com.maps.steps"},
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:src/test/reports/TestReport.html"},
        tags = "@VD"
)
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class CucumberTestRunner extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Scenarios", dataProvider = "scenarios")
    public void runCucumberScenario(PickleWrapper pickleWrapper, FeatureWrapper featureWrapper) throws Throwable {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(pickleWrapper.getPickle());
    }

    @DataProvider(parallel = false)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideScenarios();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() {
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }
}
```

- When I am running the TestNg.xml file in the IntelliJ, I am setting Spring Profile as DEV by passing  `-Dspring.profiles.active=DIT` in VM argument
- The value of promotionService.host in application-DEV.yml file is pointed to DEV endpoint [Https://SOME-DEV-HOST]
- In the test I am updating the the property of promotionService.host to point to the host of spring-boot application running as a Generic Container [Https://localhost:someRANDOMPORT]
- But when I inspect the logs it is still calling DEV end point but not the localhost.

How to update the spring-properties dynamically in the test ?

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber-Spring uses Springs test context manager. The test context is derived from the class annotated with `@CucumberContextConfiguration`. So the `@DynamicPropertySource` annotated method must be in that class.

Code organisation wise it would be best to have a separate class without hooks and step definitions dedicated to this. You can then autowire this class this into your step definition classes.

But this won't solve your problem fully.

Cucumber invokes its before hook after starting the sprint context so. So you will not be able to start your containers in time that way.

If your tests always need the container you could consider using a `ContextCustomizer`. See [How to reuse Testcontainers between multiple SpringBootTests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62425598/how-to-reuse-testcontainers-between-multiple-springboottests/74014960#74014960)

If not, you'll have to put your `CucumberContextConfiguration` annoated class in a sibling package and include it explicitly into a suite dedicated to running tests with a container.

It's one of the unfortunate limitations of Cucumber.