# TestContainers - disable test containers based on spring profile

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, integration-testing, junit5, testcontainers

I am new to test containers and working on writing integration test cases using spring boot and test containers.

I have to write multiple test cases and i should be able to switch between different environments to run these test cases. To achieve this, i am the following the below approach and it is working fine.

--to run the test cases locally

```
@SpringBootTest(classes=TestProjectApplication.class)
@ActiveProfiles("local")
public class IntegrationTestLocal {

    static {
        DockerComposeContainer container =
                new DockerComposeContainer(new File("/home/test/docker/mock.yml"))
                        .withExposedService("test-container-sybase", 5011);
        container.start();
    }
}
```

--to run the test cases on dev

```
@SpringBootTest(classes= TestProjectApplication.class)
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class IntegrationTestDev {

}
```

But the problem is, all my test cases should extend any one of these class. All the test cases should not be dependent on the environment.

```
public class IntegrationTest extends IntegrationTestLocal/IntegrationTestDev {

    @Test
    void test(){
        
    }
}
```

So, is there anyway i can achieve this like getting the active profile inside static block and disable test containers if needed. Something like this, having one single base class and create containers only of the profile is local? or any other better approach?

```
@SpringBootTest(classes=TestProjectApplication.class)
public class IntegrationTest {

    @Value("${active.profile}")
    private static String activeProfile;

    static {
        if("local".equals(activeProfile)){
            DockerComposeContainer container =
                    new DockerComposeContainer(new File("/home/bharathip/test/docker/mock.yml"))
                            .withExposedService("test-container-sybase", 5011);
            container.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In Spring, the static block in a class is executed when the class is loaded by the JVM, before any instances of the class (i.e., Spring beans) are created. Therefore, the static block in a Spring bean class will be executed before the bean is created by the Spring container. so you will not get the active profile inside the static block.

Comment: Yes, is there any other approach to achieve this?

Comment: You'll want to use a `ContextCustomer` like so https://stackoverflow.com/a/74014960/3945473 once in place, in `customizeContext` you can check which profiles are active.